# jQuery document width with math

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, width

I'm still learning jQuery. It's going very slowly, but eh, at least I'm learning. Today I need help with a page width function. I need a jQuery script that gets the page width, does a lot of math, and then sets variables to the width. This script would be VERY helpful to me, because I tend to use this a lot and I always get stuck. Here's what I'd like it to do:

1. Get the page width.
2. Subtract 30 from the page width.
3. Divide the (page width - 30) by 6.
4. Subtract 180 from ((page-width - 30)/6).
5. Set the width of the class .normal to the width of (((page-width - 30)/6)-180).
6. And lastly, I need to set the class of .wide to 2(((page-width -30)/6)-180).

Basically, this SHOULD create 4 even columns of entries with the class of .normal, but have one column with the class of .wide be twice the size of normal entries.

If anyone can help me with this, it would be awesome. I have no clue where to start at all in this.

EDIT: An example of what I'd like this to look like is [HERE](http://idkheylol.tumblr.com/), except that should be full screen except for a 15 pixel margin on each side, and change widths of posts and elements depending on screen resolution.

Comment: What are you going to do? Do you just want to have those positionings? Then you should use css for that. Do you want the boxes to fill your whitespaces? Then you should take a look at masonry. For further readings in using width with jQuery, take a look at http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=width&go=

Comment: That page has masonry. And I can't use CSS? I need the page to be filled with 4 columns + 1 larger column no matter what the page width is, that's why I need to use jQuery to do all that math.

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave the css stuff (aligning the .normal-elements right to the .wide-element) to you (should be done easily with float:right or absolute positioning) and simply show the jQuery code:

```javascript
// you don't need the '$' in your variable - I just think this is more readable
$width = ($(document).width() - 30)/6 - 180;
$('.normal').width($width);
$('.wide').width(2*$width);
```

Be aware that this does not set the width of the class 'normal'/'wide' (like you'd do in your css stylesheet) but the width of every dom-element that has the class 'normal' or 'wide'.

Comment: *What* didn't work? What *exactly* do you need? Css to align the stuff? jQuery code to change the width (what my snippet does - at least in my firefox)? Something else? Edit: *someone* deleted the "didn't work" comment just previous to mine...

Comment: I need jQuery to subtract 30 from the document width, then divide that width by 5, then subtract 180 from THAT width. Then I need JQuery to set the width of #entry's tagged as .normal as the (((doc-30)/5)-180), and jQuery to set the width of #entry's tagged as .wide as the same thing, but twice as big, so 2*.

Comment: So (except from dividing by 6 instead of 5) what is the difference to the code I posted? Maybe the documentation of [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) could be your friend...

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 calculation capabilities that can do this for you:

```
.normal {
    display: block;
    width: calc(((100% - 30px) / 6) - 180px);
}
```

That's the pure CSS spec, there are vendor extensions: `-moz-calc` and `-webkit-calc`, etc.

Comment: I didn't know about that one. Unfortunately there's [not much browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) for it yet.

Comment: It didn't even work properly in Firefox. I really need this script to work. D:

Comment: Firefox requires the -moz-calc vendor extension... so it would be: `.normal { width: -moz-calc(...); }`

Comment: This is cool.  Can't wait until CSS3 is THE standard.  If only that pesky IE would go away.

Answer (score 0):

You need 4 even columns of entries with the class of .normal, but have one column with the class of .wide be twice the size of normal entries which means there are 5 columns, 4 with same width and 5th column twice the width of individual column. I think this is what you need.

```
var oneColumnWidth = ($(document).width()/6);

$('.normal').width(oneColumnWidth);
$('.wide').width(oneColumnWidth * 2);
```

Comment: You're the only one who actually understands what i need, haha. Do you have a skype I can add you on? It's not working, but you seem smart so I'd like to explain in further detail.

Comment: It's hard to explain. Do you either have a skype? If not we can go into chat on here.

Comment: I don't know how... I'm new to this website. :c

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to chat. :/